# How to change url length in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using FormRequest.from_response module in scrapy to scrape some bus information. Whenever I run my spider, it ignores the post request by giving the following information:

```
DEBUG: Ignoring link (url length > 2083):
```

The details mentioned in scrapy docs are as follows:

```
URLLENGTH_LIMIT
Default: 2083
Scope: contrib.spidermiddleware.urllength
```

Can anyone please tell me how to change this setting ?

Comment: Did you try increasing this limit in your project `settings.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that this error was raised because I was not specifying the method type for posting the request. I just added the following in my FormRequest arguments and everything is working fine:

```
method="POST"
```

Answer (score 3):

In settings.py of scrappy
add this

```
URLLENGTH_LIMIT = (integer)
```

learn more [scrappy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/settings.html)